# Skip NA using Case_When

Tags: r, dplyr

Have a situation where my code uses `arrange` for a certain column - say `col1`, but if that row does not have data available for that column, then I'd like it to use the `col2`, if `col2` is not available, then I'd like it to use `col3` and so on until `col6`.

so currently:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("NA", "1999-07-01", "NA"), 
                 col2 = c("NA", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col3 = c("04-01-2015", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col4 = c("04-01-2015", "NA", "01-12-2009"),
                 col5 = c("NA", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col6 = c("04-01-2015", "09-22-2011", "NA"),
                 id = c(1251,16121,1209))
```

currently something similar to this is applied, but need to make it more flexible for the different cases mentioned above:

```
df %>% 
mutate(col1 = as.Date(col1)) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
arrange(col1) %>% 
mutate(diff = col1 - lag(col1))
```

I was thinking to use case_when in `arrange` but not sure how to translate that into the `mutate` aspect.

Alternatively, I was thinking about just creating another column i.e:

```
    df <- df %>%
      mutate(earliestDate = case_when(
        !is.na(col1) ~ col1,
        is.na(col1) ~ col2,
        is.na(col2) ~ col3,
        is.na(col3) ~ col4, 
        is.na(col4) ~ col5))
```

but the above doesn't update the new earliestDate column to have the earliest date, just grabs the first column?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. `arrange` sorts rows based on values in specific columns. It doesn't change/manipulate data. Can you post your expected output for the sample data you give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to order rows by `earliestDate`; why not do something like this?

```
df %>%
    gather(key, date, starts_with("col")) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(earliestDate = min(as.Date(date, format = "%m-%d-%Y"), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    spread(key, date)
## A tibble: 3 x 8
## Groups:   id [3]
#      id earliestDate col1       col2       col3       col4       col5   col6
#   <dbl> <date>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>  <chr>
#1  1209. 2009-01-12   NA         01-12-2009 01-12-2009 01-12-2009 01-12… NA
#2  1251. 2015-04-01   NA         NA         04-01-2015 04-01-2015 NA     04-01…
#3 16121. 1999-07-01   07-01-1999 09-22-2011 09-22-2011 NA         09-22… 09-22…
```

Explanation: We convert data from wide to long, group by `id` and determine the `earliestDate`; we then convert data back from long to wide.

Note that dates from your sample data are not 100% consistent: for most entries you have dates in the format `"%d-%m-%Y"` except for the first entry in `col1` which is `"1999-07-01"`. I have changed this in the sample data below.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("NA", "07-01-1999", "NA"),
                 col2 = c("NA", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col3 = c("04-01-2015", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col4 = c("04-01-2015", "NA", "01-12-2009"),
                 col5 = c("NA", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col6 = c("04-01-2015", "09-22-2011", "NA"),
                 id = c(1251,16121,1209))
```

Comment: Should clarify that not look for the earliest date overall! But the earliest date given the hierarchy

Comment: @S31 In my code above, I'm not looking for the earliest date overall but for the earliest date per `id`. That's why we group by `id`.

Answer (score 0):

To start your current "NA" values are not really R's `NA` value, so convert them.

```
df[df == "NA"] <- NA
```

Then you can take advantage of the row margin option in `apply` to find the leftmost (assuming that's what you want to do and not actually build true date objects, like Maurtis' answer) value that is not missing.

```
df$left_most <- apply(df[-7], 1, function(x) x[which.min(is.na(x))])

df
        col1       col2       col3       col4       col5       col6    id left_most
1       <NA>       <NA> 04-01-2015 04-01-2015       <NA> 04-01-2015  1251     04-01-2015
2 07-01-1999 09-22-2011 09-22-2011       <NA> 09-22-2011 09-22-2011 16121     07-01-1999
3       <NA> 01-12-2009 01-12-2009 01-12-2009 01-12-2009       <NA>  1209     01-12-2009
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are two challenge in the data provided by OP.

> 1. The date format are not consistent. Sometime `year` part is in beginning and sometime its in end.
> 2. The order of preference for the columns. First `Col1` is considered and then `Col2` and so on.

To handle date in heterogeneous format one can use `parse_date_time` function from `dplyr`. And the use `coalesce` to group column is such a way that `col1` data gets preference, and then `col2` and so on.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
mutate_at(vars(1:6), funs(parse_date_time(., orders=c("ymd","mdy"),quiet=TRUE))) %>%
mutate(col = coalesce(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)) %>%
  select(id, col)

#      id        col
# 1  1251 2015-04-01
# 2 16121 1999-07-01
# 3  1209 2009-01-12
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("NA", "1999-07-01", "NA"), 
                 col2 = c("NA", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col3 = c("04-01-2015", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col4 = c("04-01-2015", "NA", "01-12-2009"),
                 col5 = c("NA", "09-22-2011", "01-12-2009"),
                 col6 = c("04-01-2015", "09-22-2011", "NA"),
                 id = c(1251,16121,1209))
```